# Error while loading images in server AWS

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, path, webpack

I have developed my application in windows and hosted in AWS Ubuntu. The application is developed using Node and React with Webpack.

Webpack config :

```js
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var combineLoaders = require('webpack-combine-loaders');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
  devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
  entry: "./src/app/client.js",
  module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
              presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
              plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-class-properties', 'transform-decorators-legacy'],
            }
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          loader: combineLoaders([
            {
              loader: 'style-loader'
            }, {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              query: {
                modules: true,
                localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
              }
            }
          ])
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
        },
        {
            test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
            loaders: [
                'file?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
                'image-webpack?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
            ]
        }
    ]
  },
  sassLoader: {
    includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, "/public/src/styles/")]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/public/src/",
    filename: "client.min.js"
  },
  plugins: debug ? [] : [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
  ],
};
```

The application works fine in my local, but not in the server. I get error in the console:

`Header.js:5 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "../../../images/icons/user.png" at webpackMissingModule (Header.js:5)`

And the error in the cmd :

```
ERROR in ./public/src/images/icons/user.png
Module build failed: Error: spawn     /home/ubuntu/dashboard/node_modules/pngquant-bin/vendor/pngquant ENOENT
at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:359:16)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
@ ./public/src/app/components/Dashboard/Media/Media.js 76:14-60
```

In my `node_modules\pngquant-bin\vendor` folder there is a `pngquant.exe` file, is that creating any issue or the directory path specified in the webpack?

**UPDATE**

`console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);` gives `undefined` in my local and server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You developed application in Windows OS and want to deploy on Ubuntu OS. I too had same problem while importing files from Windows to Linux.

1. You deploy application on Windows Server Instance because you will be using browser in Windows OS. When you import file, it will get the file path as same like Windows Server Instance file system. So actual file can store in an instance. File path gets matter here.
2. If you want to deploy app on AWS Ubuntu OS, instead of browsing files through Windows OS you can store files in Ubuntu. The reason behind is, file path gets changed when you browse through Windows OS.

I solved on deploying app in Windows Instance.

Comment: Thanks Kumaresh, but I want to deploy in ubuntu itself. Any other work around?

Comment: In code, you will get whole path of image and store the path as string. You pass string image path into linux path like /etc/images/(string_imagepath) then you will be using linux path to store into s3 bucket. This may work!